# vim keymap with ":" key

Tags: vim

How to change functionality of : key to / or comma

What is name of this functional key?

When i press `<S-:>` I would like to use this:

```
nmap <S-:> >>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm absolutely at a loss on what you are trying to achieve here, but you could just

```
:nnoremap , :
:nnoremap : ,
```

I included the reverse mapping, because, you know, <kbd>:</kbd> to start command-mode is *kind of important* to have working in vim.

Just in case you get stuck, `ZZ` is usually another way to close a window in vim (if the buffer is unmodified, usually)